# Free Software for Billing (Colombia)

Tags: software-recommendation, java, compiling, install-from-source, finance

**English**

I'm looking for a billing application (also inventories, shopping, clients, providers, accounts, etc) for small businesses. The software should adapt with Colombia's necessities. I searched for it in Google, and I found several ERP such as OpenBravo and Adempiere, but these applications are very big and difficult to use, in fact, I couldn't make them work.

I found an application called Ubifactura (made specifically for Colombia), I downloaded the Java source code, but I don't have any idea about how to compile it. I need someone to help me to compile it or just some recommendations for similar software.

The idea is to help small business from my town with one of these applications (it doesn't matter if it is for Windows or Linux), the idea is to help.

All help is welcome.

**Spanish (Español)**

Estoy buscando una aplicacion de facturacion (tambien inventario, compras, clientes, proveedores, cuentas, etc) para pequeñas empresas, que se adaptade a las necesidades de Colombia, en google encontre varios ERP como openbravo y adempiere, pero aplicaciones muy grandes y dificiles de manejas, de hecho no puede hacerlas funcionar.

Encontre un programa llamado Ubifactura, hecho para facturar en Colomabia, descarge los archivos de codigo fuente en java, pero no tengo ni idea de como ponerlo a funcionar, pues habla de eclipce, de un servsdor CVS, que no tengo ni idea de como poner a funcionar, necesito si alguien me puede ayudar a trabajar con estos archivos java, o me suguieran aplicacion de acuerdo a mis necesidades.

La idea es bebeficiar a varias pequeñas empresas de mi pueblo con una aplicacion de estas, ni importa si en entorno windows o ubuntu, la idea es aportarles algo desde el software libre.

Saludos y a la espera de respuestas.

Toda ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: I don't know if you've seen it already, but it might fit your needs: http://www.gnucash.org/

Comment: You will need to install the Java development kit (if you haven't already). The source file should contain some sort of build script, like a Makefile or Ant `build.xml`. Run this script using `make` or `ant`.

Comment: This is really two questions: One is about what applications people recommend for your needs, and the other is about how to compile and run a particular application (Ubifactura). I recommend removing the question about how to compile Ubifactura from this question and posting a new question asking how to compile it. Also, for this question, I recommend adding more information to clarify what you mean by "Colombia's necessities."  In what ways do you need an application that localizes to Colombia? Do you just need something that supports language and currency, or do you need something more?

Answer (score 1):

[Quasar Accounting](http://www.linuxcanada.com/) might meet your needs.  The most recent version is commercially licensed (with a free license for a single workstation), but an [earlier version is GPL-licensed](https://github.com/thomasn/quasar/).  I've been running the GPL version with PostGreSQL for a number of years.

It is a full accounting package with a chart of accounts, vendors, clients, quotes, invoices, payments, products, lots of pricing and discounting options, etc.